# Android's datepicker date shown

Tags: java, android, eclipse, datepicker

I can't find any method or solution to set the exact date shown on `datepicker`'s spinners.

My problem is that I want to set the date through those spinners and then, when the user wants to edit that date, it would be great to start the spinners from that day and not from the maximum possible (the default).

Answer (score 0):

[DatePickerDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DatePickerDialog.html) has two constructors, both of which accept parameters for setting the initial date.

Comment: What should i put into the first paramater? Tbh dont know what Concept should be - in case i want just change default shown numbers on spinners upon opening

Comment: It might help if you posted your code that creates the DatePickerDialog. First parameter is the Context - not sure why it's confusing to you.

Answer (score 0):

`DatePicker` has [`updateDate()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html#updateDate%28int,%20int,%20int%29), which presumably updates the date.

Comment: it just set output of the picker to that value so its doesnt matter what you pick on spinners it always output the same or just mine does it though